# Joining two tables and returning a DbSet object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join

In my IdentityModels class I have a property called Reports like below

```
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
```

In my database there is a table with the same name which this property pulls the data from.

I also have a model called Report that (in addition to some other properties) has these

```
public class Report
{
    //...
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Column("reporter_id")]
    public string ReporterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("report_text")]
    public string ReportText { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I also have a view that is a strong view with Report as its model.

Where I ran into a problem is that my model has reporterId which is a foreign key to different table called `AspNetUsers` that has the user details.

I want to display the user name not the id and because the Reports table only has the userId there is no way for me to display the user name.

What would be a good way of making a `user_name` field in the `AspNetUsers` table be part of my model?  There obviously has to be a `join` statement somewhere between the `reports` table and `aspNetUsers` table but I'm not sure how best to do this.

Comment: can you put an `AspNetUsers' model also?

Comment: you didn't put `userId` on `Report` model also ?

Comment: I have userId (property called `ReporterId`) in my `Report` model but I need to use 'userName' from 'AspNetUsers' table because what I want to display in the user name not user id

Comment: Oh..why can't you put it as `userId` then ? it is giving Wrong impression no ?

Comment: @Sampath I will need a user model also you are correct but how will I bind that the report and user objects to the view? right now my view is bound with `@model IEnumerable<Proj.Models.Report>`

Comment: can you put an `AspNetUsers` model code also?

Comment: I don't have the `AspNetUsers` model yet just the `Report` model.

Comment: then how you're going to join them ?

Comment: That is where i am stuck :) So if I make the aspNetUser model, (easy) which has the username, how do I bind that to my view?  Right now my view is bound with `@model IEnumerable<Proj.Models.Report>`  Thank you for helping me!

Comment: is this `db first` or what ?

Comment: what is the relationship between `Report : aspNetUser` ? `1:1` or `1:M` or `M:M` ?

Comment: Reports.reporter_id = aspNetUsers.id; 1 user to many reports

Comment: Hi @ska.dev  , is it a must for you to use join to get username? If not you can try using ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer may not be helpful to you but I'm will still post it, ViewModel are specifically used for this kind of situation where you need to have two or more tables data displayed in a view.

First , you will need to create a ViewModel lets call it `UserReportViewModel`. In this view model, you will include an additional property `UserName` that will pull the username based on `ReporterId`.

```
public class UserReportViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Column("reporter_id")]
    public string ReporterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("report_text")]
    public string ReportText { get; set; }

    public string UserName{ get; set; }
}
```

Then , assuming you are using LINQ to retrieve the report:

```
Dim ReportList As List(Of UserReportViewModel) = New List(Of UserReportViewModel)
ReportList = dbContext.Reports.Select(Function(x) New UserReportViewModel With {
                                                        .State = x.State, _
                                                        .ReporterId= x.ReporterId, _
                                                        .UserName= dbContext.Users.Find(x.ReporterId).UserName, _
                                                        .ReportText = x.ReportText, _
                                                  }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your models as shown below.

```
    public class Report
    {
        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("report_text")]
        public string ReportText { get; set; }

    }

  public class AspNetUser
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set;} 
   }
```

Your Query should be like this :

```
var query =
(from u in db.AspNetUsers
from r in u.Reports
select new { UserName = u.Name, ReportText = r.ReportText }).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry, where exactly do I use the LINQ query?

Comment: I didn't get you ? did you change your models as shown above ?